# arm-none-linux-gnueabi 4.6.1 VS 4.8.1

Tags: performance, gcc, arm

Recently I was using the gcc cross compiler for arm (arm-none-linux-gnueabi) to compile my code for a platform that is using Cortex A9. I changed my compiler to 4.8.1 and unfortunately using the same flags and parameters while I was compiling my code, the execution time increased?

Is this possible? I thought that higher versions are optimized in comparison with previous versions.

Comment: You should supply more information.

Comment: Yes, it is always possible.  Generally, it maybe a performance regression (many exist and can be found by consulting the `gcc` bugzilla).  However, there may have been a bug in 4.6.1 and it is fixed in 4.8.1 and as a result of the bug fix, the code runs slower.

Comment: As per Auselen, if your question is only "Is this possible?", it is not a good stack overflow question.  If you give specifics on the code with a limited test case, people could give advice or an anser.  Some things like *strict math*, etc. may affect performance, but not really be a *bug*.  Ie, you may need additional compiler options with 4.8.1.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. The previous version of the gcc compiler that I was using was 4.6.1. I am compiling my code with the following flags: 

-Ofast -fprefetch-loop-arrays -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9. 

My code is about efficient implementation of array functions like rotation of a 2D array ( using tiling for taking advantage of cache locality ) or shifting the lines of a 2D array ( that means that my output is bigger than my input). I know that my description is still abstract. My main point is if a new gcc version is always better than an older version

Comment: **ALWAYS** is a very strict condition.  Code size may increase due to it being faster, more correct, or a bug.  For large arrays, memory bandwidth is always an issue.  All ARM systems will have different memory bandwidths.  `gcc` can only guess (usually that memory is fast).  For instance, some people find `-marmv5` actually gives better performance/benchmark on a Cortex-A9; no reference right now.  Compiler writers struggle with correct first, fast next.  Fast is hard as it differs by hardware.  Try `-Os` as well; this can be faster on different hw.

Comment: Also, for both 4.6.1 and 4.8.1, there are patches which may fix performance bugs.  I would update to 4.6.3 and 4.8.2 if possible.  However, the compiler flags may affect performance in ways that seem strange.  Usually it is due to your systems memory performance versus the 'ideal gcc' version.  Commercial compilers often outperform gcc (or they go out of business).